# Magento2 - How to make same order increment_id number for multiple stores under single website?

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2, multistore

I have **4 stores** running under single Magento 2 installation. Right now each store has its own order number series.

For Example:

> Order Number
>   Store 1:   100000001
>   Store 2:   200000001
>   Store 3:   300000001
>   Store 4:   400000001

But We want same order number series for all, For example.

> Order Number
>   Store 1:   100000001
>   Store 2:   100000002
>   Store 3:   100000003
>   Store 4:   100000004

Please let me know the solution for Magento2, I'm running version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `sales_sequence_meta`

All sequence_table row are used on same increment table Example 'sequence_order_1'
example: 
UPDATE `sales_sequence_meta` SET `sequence_table` = 'sequence_order_1'. where meta_id =?? ()

Note: Empty all previous Quote and invoice related row  OR Use on highest 
sequence_value table on this tables (sequence_order_1, sequence_order_0,sequence_order_2)